# Unable to build in AMD-GPU kernel module: This feature depends on another which has been configured as a module

Tags: linux-kernel, dependencies, kernel-module, amd-gpu

I am trying to build-in the AMD-GPU kernel module to my custom kernel. However, I am only able to build it as a module. When I press y in order to build it a text box appears that reads: 
  `This feature depends on another which has been configured as a module. As a result, this feature will be built as a module.`

My question is, what kernel modules does the AMD-GPU module depend on so that I can build it into the kernel?

Apologies for my wording and formatting, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if you type modinfo amdgpu modinfo gives you all the info about the kernel object.

AMDGPU depends:  drm,drm_kms_helper,ttm,i2c-algo-bit